# Boot M5 Bug: server.session.persistent is defaulting on, and ignoring false

Tags: spring-boot

Any suggestions on where to better post M5 bugs is appreciated. Test passes on latest 1.2.6, fails on 1.3.0.M5. Steps to reproduce:

```
1. Create a web starter project using 1.3.0.M5
2. Add a simple test method to add a session variable
3. Start the server on either your desktop, or targeted platform (linux)
4. Hit the endpoint a few times.
5. restart the container.
6. hit it again, note the counter continues on
```

Anything like the following will suffice to test. Another tip if figured out while using Boot: always run with -Djava.io.tmpdir="target" . This will make troubleshooting "hidden" files a lot easier

```
@RequestMapping("/addSessionVar")
public String addSessionVar( HttpSession session)  {

    if ( session.getAttribute( SAMPLE_SESSION_VAR ) == null ) session.setAttribute( SAMPLE_SESSION_VAR, new AtomicInteger(0) );

    AtomicInteger val =  (AtomicInteger ) session.getAttribute( SAMPLE_SESSION_VAR ) ;
    int curValue = val.incrementAndGet() ;

    logger.info( "Updated session variable {} : {}", SAMPLE_SESSION_VAR, curValue ) ;

    return "Updated session variable " + SAMPLE_SESSION_VAR + " to: " + curValue ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property to configure session persistence is `server.session.persistent`, not `server.session.persist`. It defaults to `false` unless you have Spring Boot's DevTools on the classpath.

If you're seeing behaviour that's at odds with this please [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new).

Comment: Hi Andy - that was typo in title (now fixed).  As mentioned - dev tools is not on the classpath as this is reproducable in 3 clicks in STS using only web starter. I will try to add to open issues